# docker-compose up error for django and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker

I am trying to configure Django and MySql application with Docker containers.

For Django I am using python:3.7-slim  image and for MySql mysql:5.6.

When I run `docker-compose up` it returns an error stated below -

```
ERROR: for app_mysql_db_1  Cannot start service mysql_db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint app_mysql_db_1 (c647d4793a198af2c09cc52d08191fb2cd984025ad0a61434ad1577d9dcccebe): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
```

I run command `docker ps -a` to check docker status and found that mysql container was created but the python container status was exited.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
7d91795e0bae        mysql:5.6           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago      Created                                        app_mysql_db_1
fa0419ad0f21        e0bf94710555        "/bin/sh -c 'adduser…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 2 minutes ago                       pedantic_faraday
```

can someone rewrite or suggest the modification for the configurations.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc  -y
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  eitan-application:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./eitan:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      && python3 manage.py makemigrations
      && python3 manage.py migrate"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my-app-db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'mysql_db',
        'PORT': 3307,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind: address already in use` suggests that you have some local database running. If you don't need to access database outside of docker-compose network don't expose port 3306. So I'd try to test it without

```yaml
...
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
...
```

Also in `settings.py` you connect to port `mysql_db:3307` so change it to default port 3306.

Even if you expose database port to some other port on localhost then settings.py connects using `mysql_db` network, so you shouldn't change this port in django settings.